# Filter Values in Python of a Pandas Dataframe of a large array with multiple conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataset that I need to filter once a value has been exceeded but not after based on a groupby() of a second column. Here is an example of the dataframe:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['UWI']).[df.DIP > 85].reset_index(drop = True)
```

where I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
     UWI     DIP
0     17     70 
1     17     80 
2     17     90
3     17     80
4     17     83
5     2      62
6     2      75
7     2      87
8     2      91
```

I want the returned dataframe to look like this:

```
     UWI     DIP
0     17     90
1     17     80
2     17     83
3     2      87
4     2      91
```

This is a large dataframe so efficiency would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC using `cummax`

```
df[df.DIP.gt(85).groupby(df['UWI']).cummax()]
   UWI  DIP
2   17   90
3   17   80
4   17   83
7    2   87
8    2   91
```